# How do I find a sub sequence of a given length within a sequence such that the sum of that sub sequence is max?

Tags: algorithm, math, dynamic-programming

For ex -:
Let the sequence be = {1, 8, 2, 9} and the length of sub sequence = 2 then the max sum that can be obtained is from the sub sequence {8, 9} and that sum is 8 + 9 = 17.
How do I write an algorithm for this?

Comment: How is it different from finding K largest elements in an array?

Comment: Do you want a simple algorithm (such as already given by Luk), a fast one for long sequences, a fast one for long subsequences, or other? What work have you done on this problem so far, and just where are you stuck? Check the [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not completely clear and there is no work shown by the questioner.

Answer (score 0):

Easy.

Just scan the sequence keeping two highest numbers. Pseudocode:

```
Initialize m1 and m2 to lowest possible element (0 or -max int)
for each item in the sequence:
  if item > m1 then
    m2 = m1
    m1 = item
```

after the loop output m2+m1

This doesn't take to account sequences smaller than 2 elements, but you can easily add this edge case.

If you would go for any K instead of 2, just use collection (array) of K elements instead of 2 variables.

This is O(n).

Comment: Actually, if `k` (the number of elements in the subsequence) is large, it becomes a much higher order, the exact order depending on just how you check for the current smallest saved value, remove the current smallest saved value, and add the new value to the saved list. Those, of course, mostly depend on the data structure that stores the currently saved largest values. Your given algorithm is simple but not the quickest for large `k`.